# Flash as3 Calling methods in one class to another class which is placed on stage.

Tags: flash, events, interface, actionscript

I have main class with two child added, one is canvas and second is panel.

Canvas class:

In this class one object is added which is text field, and one method "doBold" added here, so this method will do bold the text field object.

Panel class:

In the panel class i have one button which have added a mouse event listener.

Now i want to call doBold method by clicking that button which is placed in panel class. I know it can be done using custom event, but could it be possible using interface? if yes then how it would be....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show us your code snippet.. it would be better for us to help you with actual codes...

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a number of ways that you can do this, depending on how you have your classes setup.

I am assuming you have at minimum, something along the lines of:

```
public class Canvas
{
   ...
    public function doBold() { 
       //some stuff
    }
   ...
}

-------

public class Panel 
{
    ....
    var myButton:Sprite = //definition details. 
    myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
    ....
}

------

public class Main
{
   var canvas:Canvas = //instance of your canvas class
   var panel:Panel = //instance of your panel class
}
```

**Option 1:Dispatching Custom Event**

- Setup a custom event class
- Setup a listener for that custom event after you initialize your canvas object
- Dispatch that even from the onClickEvent within your Panel class.

Here is a great tutorial on the details for setting this up:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-events-basix--active-10018

**Option 2:Simplest way, but not very scalable**
Rather than setup the event listener for your button in the Panel class you could assign it in your main class. This would require that myButton be a public var within the Panel class.

So in Main you would have something like:

```
panel.myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
...
private function onMouseClick(evt:MouseEvent) {
    canvas.doBold(evt.target);
}
```